# Why can't I see the colour of an object from 3ds Max in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, textures

I want to make a room in OpenGl with Visual Studio 2010 and add some objects like a chair, carpet etc. I designed the walls only by using textures. I have some problems when I try to import objects from 3DS Max. I see the object, but it's all white. I should be able to see its colour.What did I do wrong? Thanks.
 [image] 
<-My object on 3ds MAx
[image]
<-OpenGL

`#include "stdafx.h"
    #include "tga.h"
    #include "glut.h"
    #include <gl/gl.h>
    #include "glm.h"`

```
int screen_width=1040;
int screen_height=580;


GLuint skyboxTexture[6];//skybox 
GLfloat fSkyboxSizeX, fSkyboxSizeY, fSkyboxSizeZ; //box size on X, Y and Z axes
GLMmodel *3dsobj;

GLfloat fGlobalAngleX, fGlobalAngleY, fGlobalAngleZ; //global rotation angles

void initOpenGL()
{
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)screen_width/(GLfloat)screen_height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 

glGenTextures(6,skyboxTexture);

loadTGA("Textures\\greywall.tga",skyboxTexture[0]); 
loadTGA("Textures\\carpet2.tga",skyboxTexture[1]);  
loadTGA("Textures\\wallpaper.tga",skyboxTexture[2]);    
loadTGA("Textures\\wallpaper.tga",skyboxTexture[3]);    
loadTGA("Textures\\green.tga",skyboxTexture[4]);    
loadTGA("Textures\\wallpaper.tga",skyboxTexture[5]);    
//set skybox size
fSkyboxSizeX =60.0;
fSkyboxSizeY =9.0;
fSkyboxSizeZ =60.0;


 }



////////////////////////////////////////
// function used to create the skybox //
////////////////////////////////////////

void DrawSkybox (GLfloat sizeX, GLfloat sizeY, GLfloat sizeZ)
{
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //enable 2D texturing


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// please consult the orientation convention for this skybox    //
// ("orientation_convention.png" file in the "Textures" folder) //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//negative x plane
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyboxTexture[0]); //select the current texture
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 6);glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, -sizeZ); //assign each corner     of the texture to a 3D vertex in the OpenGL scene
    glTexCoord2f(0, 6);glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ); //(0,0) is the left lower corner, while (1,1) is the right upper corner of the texture
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 0);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
glEnd();

//negative y plane
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyboxTexture[1]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 6);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 6);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 0);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
glEnd();

//negative z plane
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyboxTexture[2]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 6);glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 6);glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 0);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
glEnd();

//positive x plane
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyboxTexture[3]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 6);glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 6);glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 0);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
glEnd();

//positive y plane
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyboxTexture[4]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 6);glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 6);glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 0);glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, -sizeZ);
glEnd();

//positive z plane
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyboxTexture[5]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 6);glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 6);glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(6, 0);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //disable 2D texuring
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
///DrawModel                              ///
//////////////////////////////////////////////
void drawModel(GLMmodel *pmodel,char*filename,GLuint mode)
{ 
if(!pmodel)
{ 
    pmodel=glmReadOBJ(filename);
    //printf("read the model\n");
    if(!pmodel)
    { 
        exit(0); 
    }  
} 

//generate facet normal vectors for model 
glmFacetNormals(pmodel); 
//generate vertex normal vectors (called after generating facet normals) 
glmVertexNormals(pmodel,90.0);

glmDraw(pmodel,mode); 

}

void renderScene(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
//place the camera 1.2 units above the negative Y plane of the skybox
gluLookAt(0.0, -fSkyboxSizeY + 1.2 , 3.0, 0.0, -fSkyboxSizeY + 1.2, -10.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

//set global rotation on the X,Y and Z axes
glRotatef(fGlobalAngleX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(fGlobalAngleY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(fGlobalAngleZ, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

//draw skybox
glPushMatrix();     
    DrawSkybox(fSkyboxSizeX, fSkyboxSizeY, fSkyboxSizeZ);
glPopMatrix();

     glTranslatef(0.0, -fSkyboxSizeY + fTreeSize, 0.0);

//draw the tree slice
/*glPushMatrix();
    DrawSingleTreeTexture(fTreeSize);
glPopMatrix();*/


glPushMatrix(); 
  // glTranslatef(-30,0 ,0);
   glRotatef(30, 0, 1, 0);
 // glTranslatef(3, -20,-200);
   //place the tree on the negative Y plane of the skybox
    glTranslatef(19, -fSkyboxSizeY + fTreeSize+10, -6);
   glScalef(0.1,0.1,0.1);
   drawModel(3dsobj,"myObj.obj",GLM_NONE|GLM_FLAT); 
glPopMatrix();

glutSwapBuffers(); //swap the buffers used in the double-buffering technique
}

void changeSize(int w, int h)
{
screen_width=w;
screen_height=h;

if(h == 0)
    h = 1;

float ratio = 1.0*w/h;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
gluPerspective(45.0f, ratio, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{

switch(key)
{
    case 't':
        //process
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 27: //esc
        exit(1);
        break;
    //control the global Y rotation angle using 'a' and 'd'
    case 'a': 
        fGlobalAngleY += 1;
        if (fGlobalAngleY >= 360) //clamp the rotation angle in the [0,360) interval
            fGlobalAngleY = (GLint)fGlobalAngleY % 360;
        break;
    case 'd':
        fGlobalAngleY -= 1;
        if (fGlobalAngleY <= -360) //clamp the rotation angle in the [0,360) interval
            fGlobalAngleY = (GLint)fGlobalAngleY % 360;         
        break;
    //control the global X rotation angle using 'w' and 's'
    case 'w':
        fGlobalAngleX += 1;
        if (fGlobalAngleX >= 360) //clamp the rotation angle in the [0,360) interval
            fGlobalAngleX = (GLint)fGlobalAngleX % 360;         
        break;
    case 's':
        fGlobalAngleX -= 1;
        if (fGlobalAngleX <= -360) //clamp the rotation angle in the [0,360) interval
            fGlobalAngleX = (GLint)fGlobalAngleX % 360; 
        break;
    //control the global Z rotation angle using 'q' and 'e'
    case 'q':
        fGlobalAngleZ += 1;
        if (fGlobalAngleZ >= 360) //clamp the rotation angle in the [0,360) interval
            fGlobalAngleZ = (GLint)fGlobalAngleZ % 360; 
        break;
    case 'e':
        fGlobalAngleZ -= 1;
        if (fGlobalAngleZ <= -360) //clamp the rotation angle in the [0,360) interval
            fGlobalAngleZ = (GLint)fGlobalAngleZ % 360; 
        break;      
}


}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//Initialize the GLUT library
glutInit(&argc, argv);
//Set the display mode
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
//Set the initial position and dimensions of the window
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutInitWindowSize(screen_width, screen_height);
//creates the window
glutCreateWindow("First OpenGL Application");
//Specifies the function to call when the window needs to be redisplayed
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
//Sets the idle callback function
glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
//Sets the reshape callback function
glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
//Keyboard callback function
glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);
//Initialize some OpenGL parameters
initOpenGL();
//Starts the GLUT infinite loop
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you call `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `glmDraw()` with `GLM_NONE|GLM_FLAT` as your mode.  You want `GLM_SMOOTH` and `GLM_TEXTURE` in there instead.

In [the header for GLM](http://www.cs.manchester.ac.uk/ugt/COMP37111/glm/glm.h), `glmDraw()`'s different mode arguments are listed:

```
GLvoid
glmDraw(GLMmodel* model, GLuint mode);
/* glmList: Generates and returns a display list for the model using
 * the mode specified.
 *
 * model    - initialized GLMmodel structure
 * mode     - a bitwise OR of values describing what is to be rendered.
 *            GLM_NONE    -  render with only vertices
 *            GLM_FLAT    -  render with facet normals
 *            GLM_SMOOTH  -  render with vertex normals
 *            GLM_TEXTURE -  render with texture coords
 *            GLM_FLAT and GLM_SMOOTH should not both be specified.  
 */
```

Comment: Still not working. I modified:    drawModel(3dsobj,"myObj.obj",GLM_SMOOTH|GLM_TEXTURE);

Comment: You're going to have to bind your textures as well.  Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.3dcodingtutorial.com/Textures/Loading-Textures.html) will help.

Comment: I'll try this.If I don't get any results, I'll come back. Thanks!